# How to find rank of an element in stl set in O(logn)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

I want to find rank of an element in stl set. I am able to traverse from beginning to that element and find out its rank but that is taking O(n). Is there any method to find the rank in O(logn).

Answer (score 6):

No; a balanced tree does not need to store the number of descendants of each node, which is required to more quickly compute `distance( s.begin(), iter )` for `std::set s` and iterator `iter` (which is what I suppose you mean). Therefore the information simply doesn't exist except by counting the items one by one.

If you need to perform many such computations, copy the `set` into a sorted, random-access sequence such as `vector` or `deque`, but then modification of the sequence becomes expensive.

A tree data structure that does what you ask probably exists in a free library somewhere, but I don't know of one.

Comment: I can create  a balanced BST and use it. But I read somewhere that we can find rank in std::set. Thats y curious to know how to find it.

Comment: @user2613413 If "rank" is what I just described, then the notation to find it is what I mentioned: `std::distance( s.begin(), iter )`. But the algorithm is just a simple O(N) loop. If you substitute a suitable container, `distance` should employ an O(log N) algorithm instead, but no such container exists in the Standard Library. For `vector` and `deque`, it is O(1).

Comment: @Potatoswatter Boost.MultiIndex does provide random access funtionality by adding some extra pointer per node in the tree.

Comment: @TemplateRex Random access means O(1) to increment an iterator by any distance. I can't believe that merely adding one pointer to each node exposes an O(1) path from each node to any other. It sounds like those pointers go to a central table which needs to be updated in O(N) for various operations. To know how far you're going by skipping a subtree, you need the total size of the subtree, not a pointer. And keeping those sizes updated is more expensive on average than more popular methods like red-black.

Comment: Tnx, upon closer reading of the docs, Boost.MultiIndex appears to do the same as Boost.Container's flat_set, i.e. keeping a sorted vector of indices and 1 pointer per node into that vector. This does give random access iterators but at the cost of linear insertion/erase. I updated my answer so that now only Boost.Container is mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called an [Order Statistic Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). If you are using GNU C++ library, you should have an extension available for building order statistic trees. A short example is given below:

```
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;
using namespace pb_ds;

typedef tree<
int, /* key type */
null_mapped_type, /* value type */
less<int>, /* comparison */
rb_tree_tag, /* for having an rb tree */
tree_order_statistics_node_update> order_set;

int main()
{
    order_set s;
    s.insert(10);
    s.insert(20);
    s.insert(50);
    s.insert(25);

    printf("rank of 25 = %d\n", s.order_of_key(25));
}
```

Output should be `rank of 25 = 2`. For more examples, you can see [this file](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/ext/pb_ds/example/tree_order_statistics.cc).

Answer (score 2):

The functionality of a sorted vector suggested by @Potatoswatter is provided by the [`flat_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) from [**Boost.Container**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container.html). The documentation lists the following trade-offs

- Faster lookup than standard associative containers
- Much faster iteration than standard associative containers
- Less memory consumption for small objects (and for big objects if shrink_to_fit is used)
- Improved cache performance (data is stored in contiguous memory)
- Non-stable iterators (iterators are invalidated when inserting and erasing elements)
- Non-copyable and non-movable values types can't be stored
- Weaker exception safety than standard associative containers (copy/move constructors can throw when shifting values in erasures and insertions)
- Slower insertion and erasure than standard associative containers (specially for non-movable types)

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a built-in solution if you are using GCC, but Subhasis Das's answer is somewhat outdated and will not work with newer versions of GCC due to updates. The header is now

```cpp
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
```

and the set structure is

```cpp
typedef tree<
int, 
null_type, 
std::less<int>, 
rb_tree_tag, 
tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;
```

Alternatively, if a multiset is needed, the `std::less<int>` can be repalced with `std::less_equal<int>`.

Here's a demonstration of find-by-rank:

```cpp
#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
using namespace __gnu_pbds;
#include <iostream>

typedef tree<int, null_type, std::less_equal<int>, rb_tree_tag, tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;

int main()
{
    ordered_set s;
    s.insert(10);
    s.insert(20);
    s.insert(50);
    s.insert(25);

    for(int i=24; i<=26; i++) std::cout << "Rank of " << i << ": " << s.order_of_key(i) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a lower_bound function in the STL set in C++ and this can be used to find the rank of an element in a set. Take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-lower_bound-function-in-c-stl/.