# Efficiently find number of elements in range in C++ set

Tags: c++, stl, set, time-complexity

I have a C++ `set<int> s`, and an `int a` which I know is in `s`. Is there an `O(log(size(s)))` way for me to figure out the number of elements of `s` which are less than or equal to `a`? I could use `std::distance(s.begin(), s.find(a)) + 1`, but it takes `O(size(s))` time.

Alternatively, does the STL provide a container that I can use for a set-like object that allows `O(log(size(s)))` insertion, removal, and range length queries?

Comment: @jarod42, that answers the first part of my question (with "no, there is no such way for a `set`"), but not the second part ("is there a way to do it with the STL?"). Should I leave my question as is, rewrite it, or ask a separate question?

Comment: you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18141241/5980430). AFAICT, there is no equivalent in *std*.

Comment: I would says that second part goes under *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic "*.